# Bug! Unable to load .xaml Pages in .NET 7.0 MAUI C#

Tags: c#, android-emulator, .net-6.0, maui, .net-7.0

At first I built my app with .NET 6.0 and my app is successful for Android devices, Android Emulator and Windows Machine.

After, I upgrade my project from .NET 6.0 to .NET 7.0.
My code run for Windows Machine but not for Android Emulator and Android Devices.

**The AppShell.xaml:**

```
<ShellContent
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}"
    FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"
    Shell.NavBarIsVisible="true"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
    Route="LoginPage" >

</ShellContent>

<ShellContent
ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:RegisterPage}"
FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"
Shell.NavBarIsVisible="true"
Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
Route="RegisterPage" />

<FlyoutItem Title="Home" FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">

    <ShellContent
        Title="StartGame"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:StartGame}"
        Route="StartGame" 
        Icon="play.png"/>


    <ShellContent
        Title="HighScore"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HighScore}"
        Route="HighScore" 
        Icon="high_score.png"/>

    <ShellContent
        Title="Settings"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Settings}"
        Route="Settings" 
        Icon="setting_lines.png"/>

</FlyoutItem>



<Shell.FlyoutFooter>
    <StackLayout Padding="20">
        <Button 
            Text="Sign Out" 
            Command="{Binding SignOutCommand}"
            BackgroundColor="#48bfe3"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Shell.FlyoutFooter>
```

**The AppShell.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell(AppShellViewModel appShellViewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Routing.RegisterRoute($"{nameof(LoginPage)}/{nameof(RegisterPage)}", typeof(RegisterPage));
        this.BindingContext = appShellViewModel;
    }
}
```

**I have .xaml(and .xaml.cs file) login page:**

1. with button(sign-in button).

When I touch the button the C# code is:

```
[RelayCommand]
public async Task IsValid()
{
     await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(StartGame)}");   
}
```

Error is:

```
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.AppCompatResources.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.sos/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.AppCompatResources.dll [External]
[companyname.sos] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 3842(209KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 4307KB/8615KB, paused 208us,172us total 8.310ms
```

The error called after StartGame() contructor

2. with button(Register button).
   When I touch the button the C# code is:

```
[RelayCommand]
public async Task Tap()
{
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(RegisterPage)}");
}
```

Error create in function Tap:

```
[Choreographer] Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.Intrinsics.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.sos/files/.__override__/System.Runtime.Intrinsics.dll [External]
[OnBackInvokedCallback] OnBackInvokedCallback is not enabled for the application.
[OnBackInvokedCallback] Set 'android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"' in the application manifest.
[TabLayout] MODE_SCROLLABLE + GRAVITY_FILL is not supported, GRAVITY_START will be used instead
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.sos/files/.__override__/System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll [External]
[companyname.sos] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 8073(755KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(60KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 4178KB/8356KB, paused 206us,31us total 5.703ms
```

The same code for .Net 6.0 is successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this thread as I solved the problem. I was initializing an `sqlite` database using DI, and executed a run & forget `CreateTableAsync` before returning the instance, this caused `Android` to crash after navigations. Unfortunately the crash and the error messages where not helpful at all.

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton((_) =>
{
    var database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Constants.DatabasePath, Constants.DatabaseFile);
    database.CreateTableAsync<User>(); //Run & forget create table query.
    return database;
});
```

Fixed it, by making a traditional Singleton with an awaitable `GetInstance` method that create the tables on its first initialization.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a bug, it's a changed behavior between Android SDK versions.

When you update from .NET 6 to .NET 7 you also implicitly update the Android SDK version that is targeted.

If you inspect the last bit of logging that you include, the probable solution is already provided: `Set 'android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"' in the application manifest.`

More information on that can be found here: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/custom-back/predictive-back-gesture

Comment: I Set in AndroidManifest.xml the 'android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"' but not change anything. When I touch the buttons blocks the Navigation and my Application freezes, is blocked.